# Should I use Form::submit to pre-fill form with session variables?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

I'm pretty new to both PHP and symfony, and I'm looking at the code written by one of my co-workers.
it's a simple inquiry form which has confirm page. it should remember what user entered even if the user go back from confirm pagn.
He uses session to store posted data, and Form::submit to fill the data a user previously entered (such as name, e-mail address, message body).

It works, but is it good idea to use this technique? Is there any downside to do this?

First, I can no longer use Form::isSubmitted to check if the user submitted the form (as manually calling submit() makes this flag true), though I could still use isMethod('POST').

Second, official doc uses DB instead of session to store temporary variable.
Is it good or bad to store temp data in the session?
https://symfony.com/doc/current/forms.html

I've read somewhere in stackoverflow that submit will be deleted in 3.0, but it's still there, even in official 4.0 doc.

Comment: Storing temporary data in a session is perfectly normal, as that is all that should be stored in the session..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Storing data in the session is somehwhat transient. It means when the user clears their browser cache or switches to a different browser, e.g. on another device like mobile vs. desktop, the data will not be there.

When you store the data in the database - which really only makes sense for logged in users, in order to be able to properly associate the data back to them - you could overcome the problem mentioned above, but it doesn't work as well with users who are not logged in. Also, it might mean slightly more work.

Both approaches are fine and which one is more suitable really depends on your use case and which one of the drawbacks is of more concern to you.

Submitting forms underwent a few changes. Most recently I think around calling `$form->isValid()` before `$form->isSubmitted()` will give you a deprecation warning. I'm not aware of any changes to `submit()`, but you can always check the [UPGRADE-notes](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/UPGRADE-4.0.md#form) in the release.

If you are worried about deprecation you should check your logs (usually in var/logs/dev.log) or the web profiler toolbar (on the button of your page when using the `app_dev.php`-entrypoint). When Symfony deprecates something it will appear there and usually give advice on how to modify your code to be safe in future updates.

Symfony follows Semantic Versioning and therefore only removes deprecated features in a major release (from 3 to 4 a lot of deprecated things will be removed). That means even though you have deprecation warning you should be fine with minor updates, unless the deprecation has serious security implications. Nevertheless trying to get rid of deprecation notices as soon as you update is usually a good practice for me, to keep the amount of work more manageable.